# MAE and MAPE are not consistent

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I compare two forecasting models using MAE and MAPE:

The first model gives me:

- MAE(test): 797.95725
- MAPE(test): 220.59072

The second model gives me:

- MAE(test): 823.49909
- MAPE(test): 203.40554

NOW, i'm very confused ...... which model is better. The first model has less MAE and the second model has less MAPE.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you are forecasting many time series or only one, and if the values of your time series can have different orders of magnitude. If you are comparing several time series or the values can have different orders of magnitude it is better to choose scale-independent metrics, like MAPE, MdAPE, or Theil's U-statistic.

Personally, I prefer MAPE instead of MAE, because it considers relative errors and not absolute errors.